# Input Range Width Of UITextField iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to set a UITextField's input range (not the number of characters)? You can check out my screenshot below.

[image]

I already tried implementing this: [Ellipsis at the end of UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099604/ellipsis-at-the-end-of-uitextview)

It didn't work, or I'm just doing it wrong.

What I want is to limit the size of the user's input AND make it ellipsis. The text at the left side of UITextfields are merely UILabels set as subviews.

So again... I need help in setting the range of the text input, and if the input length or width overlaps my RED MARK in my screenshot, the rest of the input will be converted to POINTS OF ELLIPSIS. And then I'm pretty sure I can now proceed to my project (example: clicking the arrow button will make a small popup that will show the full text).

I forgot to add my codes in that UITextField:

```
self.billingAddressTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
_billingAddressTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, scrollView.frame.size.width, 50);
_billingAddressTextField.delegate = self;
_billingAddressTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
_billingAddressTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textfieldLogIn.png"];
[_billingAddressTextField setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.686 green:0.686 blue:0.686 alpha:1.0]];
_billingAddressTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_billingAddressTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
[_billingAddressTextField setFont:[_billingAddressTextField.font fontWithSize:16.0f]];
[_billingAddressTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
[scrollView addSubview:_billingAddressTextField];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved, I just added a new Padding (UIView) at the left side of the UITextField (billingAddressTextField). So there are now two paddings (both side) in my UITextField.

```
UIView *paddingViewForArrowButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 25)];
_billingAddressTextField.rightView = paddingViewForArrowButton;
_billingAddressTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

UIView *paddingforBillingLeft = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25)];
_billingAddressTextField.leftView = paddingforBillingLeft;
_billingAddressTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```